# Ubuntu automatically stitching from wired to wireless. How to stop?

Tags: networking

It's a weird issue I'm facing.  If the computer sits for too long, it defaults to wireless internet instead of wired.  There isn't even any wifi for it to connect to.  It just ignores the wired connection until I change it back.

Any way to fix it?

Comment: In your preferences, select the WiFi interface, UN-check the "Auto" checkbox. Then, turn WiFi off.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a try.